# EntityNotFoundException handle using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I am working on Spring Boot Application in which I am working on Three database tables.

Worker, Task and ObjectDetail

Worker Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WORKER")
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
@ToString()
public class Worker{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(unique = true, length = 36)
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

Next Class Task

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TASK")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Task{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(unique = true, length = 36)
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "School_Id")
    private School assignWorker;

 }
```

ObjectDetail Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OBJECT_DETAIL")
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ObjectDetail{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(unique = true, length = 36)
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "taskId")
    @NotNull
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Task task;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "worker_id")
    private Worker worker;

 }
```

Project Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECT")
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id", callSuper = false)
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(unique = true, length = 36)
    private String id;

    @NotNull(message = "You must specify a name.")
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "project")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Scenario

As I mentioned I have three db tables as well as their respective Entity Classes. And Every task run for project on the specific worker and its processed data is persist into the objectDetail table.
as mentioned in above entity that we are storing worker in objectDetail and task table. and when we create object of task internally hibernate automatically get the object of worker and same for the ObjectDetail object create object of worker and task. (map by task_id of objectdetail to task object and same for rest)

Now due to some issue we need to remove the a worker entries from the worker table. Assume that directly we do not have requirement of worker on which task was run. but when we do listing of task items using hibernate we are getting

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find <packagename>.Worker with id 5bb2c8f7-c938-4343-89e2-611b39d99f90
```

I understand that its throwing because of that Worker does not exist in the db. 
I google for it and found some solution out of that one is `@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.EXCEPTION)`
But it seems like its ignoring all such records which not found.

My requirement is to ignore the worker object only instead of complete record.
I want to list all task having worker object null or having value.

I will appreciate, if anyone has suggestion for it.